# Subdomain takeover due to improper records

Tags: dns, dns-domain, domain, sub-domain

**INTRO**

On [hackerone](https://hackerone.com/reports/154425) I see a few people writing reports on subdomain takeover due to improper records (*CNAME* I believe). I want to learn this 'skill' too.

**QUESTION**

I found a snapchat (sc-cdn.net) domain which is pointing to Fastly, let's say it is *fastly.sc-cdn.net*. However, when I try to register it on Fastly, Fastly won't allow it and gives the following error

> Domain 'sc-cdn.net' is already taken by another customer.

So, that got me wondering how the user *ebrietas* succeeded in registering the domain as explained in the following Hackerone report below. Could it be because snapchat 'unclaimed' sc-cdn.net at that particular moment? Because that seems illogical and not likely to me, but if that is not the case; how could one succeed in registering it?

**THE REPORT (AGAIN)**

https://hackerone.com/reports/154425

**OUTRO**

Even if it seems impossible to register right now, it, of course, still is a bug since it could be abused in the future when the domain is 'unclaimed' or by abusing a Fastly bug; but does someone know how to register such a domain on Fastly.net? I am very curious. Trial subscription on Fastly.com is free by the way, might help. Thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 4):

Snapchat had this Fastly instance set up, but eventually cancelled their service. However, they had forgotten to remove the DNS record, which allowed this researcher to simply to register a new Fastly instance with this name.

It's obviously not vulnerable anymore because they either removed the DNS record or just registered their Fastly instance again.

```
Domain 'sc-cdn.net' is already taken by another customer.
```

This means you obviously can't register it / take it over.